# Set-PnPSearchConfiguration throws exception

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Trying to apply search configuration to Tenant through following command:

```
Set-PnPSearchConfiguration -Path "C:\temp\Search\02 - Test\searchconfig.xml" -Scope Subscription
```

But it throws follwing error:

```
Set-PnPSearchConfiguration : Invalid request: Export a new search configuration first, then use it to import if you are importing an outdated exported search configuration file
```

I am using latest version of PnP.Powershell (1.10.0)

Any body else having same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. It was working all this while and this has started just recently.

The error message I get is -
Bad request : Please export a new search configuration firstly and then use it to import if you are using a stale exported search configuration file.

Appreciate if anyone can provide solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps :

1. Go to a SPO site collection's **Search Schema** and map your Managed Property with desired Crawled property.
2. Export latest Search Configuration file from **Search Configuration Export**.
3. Use this latest file in your commnad.

The command required latest Search Configuration file.